# property aliases in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

So I have a property I want to make alias's for.

```
var default_commands = {}
default_commands['foo'] = "bar";
```

Then I want a bunch of items to alias to "foo"

So if I wanted

```
default_commands['fu'] = default_commands['foo'];
default_commands['fuu'] = default_commands['foo'];
```

How could I do that so I don't have to write that all out

I tried:

```
default_commands['fu','fuu'] = default_commands['foo'];
```

But that didn't seem to work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
["fu", "fuu"].forEach(function (alias) {
    default_commands[alias] = default_commands.foo;
});
```

This won't be an "alias" in the sense that word usually invokes:

```
default_commands.fu = 5;
console.log(default_commands.foo); // still "bar", not 5.
```

But it wasn't clear what you meant in your question.

Comment: this looks like it's doing what i want

Answer (score 0):

You can do this

```
default_commands['fu'] = default_commands['fuu'] = default_commands['foo'];
```

Comment: that's only slightly less painful to write

Answer (score 0):

Solution that is probably the most flexible:

```
function unalias (str) {
  // Use whatever logic you want to unalias the string.
  // One possible solution:
  var aliases = { "fu": "foo", "fuu": "foo" };
  return aliases[str] !== undefined ? aliases[str] : str;
}

default_commands[unalias("fu")] = 7;
default_commands[unalias("fuu")] = default_commands[unalias("foo")] + 3;
alert(default_commands.foo);
```

Why is this more flexible? Read and writes will "propagate" properly.

Comment: this seems like it's making it more complicated

Comment: @mcgrailm: I drastically changed my solution.

Answer (score 0):

The only way you can really use aliases in javascript is to use objects.

Objects are accesed in js like pointers:

Example:

```
var myobj = {hello: "world"};
var myalias = myobj;

myobj.hello = "goodbye";

console.log(myobj.hello); => // "goodbye"
console.log(myalias.hello); => // "goodbye"
```

You cant make an alias for a string, number, boolean, etc..

Example:

```
var myint = 1;
var myalias = myint;

myint = 2;

console.log(myint); => // 2
console.log(myalias); => // 1
```

PD: All types (like Array or RegExp) except Int, String, Boolean, null and undefined are treated like Objects.

Answer (score 0):

**You're over thinking it.**

```
var foo="foo",fu=foo,fuu=foo,default_commands = {};

default_commands[foo] = "bar";  console.log(default_commands[foo]);
default_commands[fu]  = "baz";  console.log(default_commands[foo]);
default_commands[fuu] = "bing"; console.log(default_commands[foo]);
```